# Android handler question

Tags: android, notifications, handler

I have an application that needs to update a ongoing_event notification. The notification has a progress bar that i need to increment every 5 minutes. I use Handlers but something about it bothers me or i simply dont understand how they work.

```
      if (progress<=24)
           {

    contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress,24,progress,false);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    progress++;
    mnNotificationManager.notify(IS_PARKED_ID, notification);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTaskProgressbar, 300000);

           }
```

here is the code. It appears that when the device screen is off the notification isn't being updated. I have used Handlers in the past but as i can recall i had them updating on every 100 milisec. So my question is, is the handler somehow paused, stop and restarted or is it something else. And do you have some suggestion like wake_lock.
Thanks in advance, Simon
**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention this is all running from a service

Answer (score 1):

From time to time the gc runs to free up memory on your device. If running from the UI thread, your notification's updater might get collected as well.

I'm using a `service` for showing ongoing notifications, this way i can be sure, that neither the service nor the notification doesn't get stopped / collected.

The communication between my activities and the service i solved with handlers, but there are plenty of techniques for that too.

Comment: It is running from a service, forgot to mention. The thing is that this happens all the time, not just some time. In the two days I've been testing this, this is the case. I'm thinking of solving this using a timer.

Comment: If the 5 minute is a fixed rate schedule, then you can use timer, and inside the tas's run method you can gather the necessary data for updating. After that you can call your handler to update the progressbar.

Comment: It's fixed so I guess I'll be using Timer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

By default, the handler run in the same process of the UI thread, so I think you'd better use a service to update the progress bar.
In this case, you want to update the UI for every 5 minute. You can use AlarmManager to start an alarm service to achieve this.

Comment: It is running from a service, but don't you think that using AlarmManager is overdoing it, because I then have to deal with Broadcasts.